# RoR Active Record Serialize JSON

Tags: ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3, encoding

I am encountering "UndefinedConversionError - "\x92" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8"

When saving to the text field: "data" with content in a CSV file

```
class ManagedFile < SomeParent
  serialize :data, JSON
```

Is there a way to avoid the error?

Comment: Is your data in a non-UTF-8 format? If so it probably needs to be converted to the correct encoding first.

Comment: Please show the code with reading CSV file